# Strange residuals pattern

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, residuals, heteroscedasticity

I fit a linear model that obviously needs some work. Here is an example of my data:

```
> glimpse(full)
Observations: 5,660
Variables: 29
$ volume    (int) 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6, 9, 3, 11, 4, 25, ...
$ April     (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ August    (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ December  (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ February  (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ January   (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ July      (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ June      (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ March     (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ May       (int) 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,...
$ November  (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ October   (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ Friday    (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ Monday    (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ Thursday  (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,...
$ Tuesday   (int) 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ Wednesday (int) 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ 2013      (int) 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,...
$ 2014      (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ 6         (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ 7         (int) 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ 8         (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,...
$ 9         (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ 10        (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ 11        (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ 12        (int) 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,...
$ 13        (int) 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,...
$ 14        (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,...
$ 15        (int) 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
```

I have dummy variables for months, days of week, and hour of day. When I create a simple linear model `lm(volume~.,full)` I get very strange residual plots. Clearly there's heteroscedasticity, but there appears to be a very distinct pattern, especially in the plot with the standardized residuals. Does anybody know what's going on here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the grid pattern you see in the scale-location plot not due to the discreteness of your dependent variable?  The sharp bottom edge in the residual plot vs. the fitted values is where volume = 1.  Why not fit a generalized linear model that would account for the discreteness with a Poisson or negative binomial distribution?

Comment: (There are many posts which discuss this issue on site.) You have count data (i.e. integers) which cannot be less than 0 and you have plenty of 0's. When you subtract a linear term from data, that boundary of 0 is a line with negative slope.  Increasing spread is expected with count data. The pattern second plot is a consequence of the first one