# How to interpret plot residuals vs fitted values?

Tags: least-squares, linear-model, linear, assumptions, nonlinearity

I run a ols regression and want now check the linearity assumption. 
I found out that i have to plot the residuals vs the fitted values and if there is no non linear pattern the linearity assumption is fullfiled.

Here is the plot:

[image]

On my opinion i would say there is no real non linear pattern so i would say the linearity asumption is fullfiled.

Am i right?

Comment: Those residuals look like they're fanning. Constant variance will be violated. Also it might be non linear something's causing those clear boundaries in your residuals. Without knowing more about the data it is hard to know why but definitely assumptions are violated currently.

Comment: But i thought if the red line is near  0  the  linearity assumption is fullfiled. For example like its explained here http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/39-regression-model-diagnostics/161-linear-regression-assumptions-and-diagnostics-in-r-essentials/

Comment: I'm not positive if it's non linear, but that boundary on the bottom left looks like an area that your predictions won't go beyond. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197694/strange-residuals-pattern Maybe you have discrete integers as your DV? Either way, the other assumptions will not hold from that scatterplot.

Comment: My depended variable is log(wage). I'am only interessted in the linearity assumption. So on your opinion the linearity assumption is fullfiled but other assumptions not ?

Comment: Looks like that boundary is happening because the model won't log 0. Yeah looks linear enough but constant variance is violated.